# Making a single API call and storing response in a service so that other components can use that response without having to make additional API calls

Tags: angular, observable, httpresponse

I want to make one API call and store the response in a service so that the data obtained from the response can be used in multiple components without making any additional API calls.

In all these cases, the chartId is the same, therefore the server returns the same response. In ngOnInit of component-1, the getChartDetail call is made once. In the same component, the server call is made again and also in component 2 which is not a related component, the call is made again. How would I prevent multiple server calls and just make the call once, store the data in a separate function and just call the function that already has the desired data?

Here is my code

In the chart service component:

```
getChartDetail(chartId){
   const url = 'test/someurl';
   return this.service.httpCall('get', url, null)
          .map(chart => this.processChart(chart));
}

processChart(chart) {
   const result = _.cloneDeep(chart);
   _.forEach(result.sections, (section) => {
        const subCategories= _.flatMap(section.categories, 'subCategories');
        _.assign(section, {
            subCategories,
            categories:undefined,
        });
   });
   return result;
}
```

In component-1

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.chartService.getChartDetail(chartId).subscribe((chart) => {
       this.data= chart.data;
   });
}

notifyAction() {
    const chartCountries = this.chartService.getCountries();
    const chartRequests = this.chartService
                              .getChartDetail(chartId)
                              .concatMap(chart =>
                                  this.chartService.listResults(
                                      this.chart.chartType,
                                      this.chart.chartVersion,
                                  )
                               ));
    Observable.zip(chartRequests, chartCountries)
        .subscribe(([settings, countries]) =>
            this.chartScore = settings;
            this.chartEvents = countries;
        });
}
```

In component-2

```
toggleButton() {
    this.chartService.getChartDetail(chartId).subscribe((chart) => {
        this.chartprofileDetail(chart);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add ChartService to the module providers array, so that a single instance is created for the entire module.

In chart.service.ts file, create a 'chart' field.

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
public class ChartService {
    private _chart: any // used for caching the value - use your defined type instead 
                           of any
    getChartDetail(chartId):Observable<any> {
        if(!this._chart) {
             const url = 'test/someurl';
             return this.service.httpCall('get', url, null)
                 .map(chart => {
                     this._chart = chart;
                     return this.processChart(chart);
                  }
             );
        } else {
            return of(this.processChart(this._chart));
        }
   }
```

}